# Apple Music tracks that are added on iTunes aren't showing up on iOS devices

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, apple-music

Currently I'm using the free trial period of Apple Music.

On iTunes, I'm adding the songs that I like to my music. Just adding not downloading.

When I'm checking my iPhone and iPad, those added songs aren't getting added to `My Music` section.

However on iPhone and iPad, I disabled automatic download for music. I don't want music to be downloaded (crappy 16GB iPhone).

I only want the songs that I added on iTunes to appear in music player on iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your iOS devices, make sure iCloud Music Library is enabled in the Music section of the Settings app.